# subscribing js client (web sockets style) to Azure Service bus

Tags: websocket, azureservicebus

I know that I can post data to azure service bus with REST methods.
My q is if I can subscribe to the bus, just like I subscribe to web sockets

Comment: did you try out ServiceBusJavascriptSDK?[https://github.com/ddobric/ServiceBusJavaScriptSdk/wiki/What-is-Azure-Service-Bus-JavaScript-SDK%3F]

Comment: yea, but it is a Rest method to get the msg. it means I will have to put js timer and keep trying to pool. I am looking for event driven api